# print winform screen

Tags: c#, winforms

I have c# winform application.

I want to print all form objects, labels,textboxes  etc..

Capture screen is not the solution for me because my form has scroll.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just doesn't work.  It is pretty inappropriate anyway, the resolution of the printer is *much* better than the resolution of your screen.  The screenshot looks very ugly on paper, especially text gets blobby with the anti-aliasing pixels becoming painfully obvious.

Bite the bullet and drop the PrintDocument component on the form.  You typically need to write a fair amount of code in the PrintPage event handler.  But it isn't hard code and it will look great and you can make it look just the way you want it.  Be sure to make it look like a report, not a screenshot.  Use PrintPreviewDialog to avoid wasting a lot of paper.  Report generators like RDLC and Crystal Reports are common solutions as well.

Comment: Just throwing out there that the first attempt at printing is going to give you a headache, but after you do it right the first time each subsequent time becomes a fairly quick and uneventful project.

Answer (score 3):

A simple google search:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287529%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: thanks. but my form is too long (with scroll). So it doesnt help me.

Comment: @Jack, I didn't try multi page form, but i do this with datagrid, the sample in http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/HowToPrintaDataGridinCsHARPand.NET11212005060838AM/HowToPrintaDataGridinCsHARPand.NET.aspx is for multiple page, the `HasMorePages` is a keyword that used for print multiple page

Answer (score 2):

try this it will make a bitmap of your form `

```
 Bitmap b = new Bitmap(this.Bounds.Width, this.Bounds.Height);
 this.DrawToBitmap(b, new Rectangle(0,0,this.Width,this.Height));
 b.Save("C:\\a.bmp");`
```

by this image you can print also rather than saving it...

Comment: This option does not 'print' all controls content. for some controls the content is omitted.

Comment: @Arce Brito - could you please state what controls / content type will be omitted?